# Modifying for loop with if conditions to apply format in R

Tags: r, lapply

I am creating a variable called indexPoints that contains a subset of index values that passed certain conditions -

```
set.seed(1)
x = abs(rnorm(100,1))
y = abs(rnorm(100,1))
threshFC = 0.5

indexPoints=c()
seqVec = seq(1, length(x))
for (i in seq_along(seqVec)){
    fract = x[i]/y[I]
    fract[1] = NaN
    if (!is.nan(fract)){
        if(fract > (threshFC + 1) || fract < (1/(threshFC+1))){
            indexPoints = c(indexPoints, i)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to recreate indexPoints using a more efficient method like apply methods (any except sapply). I started the process as shown below -

```
set.seed(1)
x = abs(rnorm(100,1))
y = abs(rnorm(100,1))
threshFC = 0.5

seqVec <- seq_along(x)
fract = x[seqVec]/y[seqVec]
fract[1] = NaN
vapply(fract, function(i){
    if (!is.nan(fract)){ if(fract > (threshFC + 1) || fract < (1/(threshFC+1))){ i}}
}, character(1))
```

However, this attempt causes an ERROR:

```
Error in vapply(fract, function(i) { : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

How can I continue to modify the code to make it in an apply format. Note: sometimes, the fract variable contains NaN values, which I mimicked for the minimum examples above by using "fract[1] = NaN".

Comment: (1) You say your function returns a `character` but you are returning `i`, a `numeric`; (2) if the condition is not true, you return nothing (`NULL`) which is also not `character`. Perhaps you want `Filter`?

Comment: Typo: `y[I]` should be `y[i]`, please verify the rest of your code is as you use on the console (because that definitely produces an error). Similarly, since you assign `fract[1] = NaN`, your `for` code always produces nothing, since `!is.nan(fract)` is *always* false.

Answer (score 6):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You tell `vapply` that you expect the internal code to return a `character`, yet the only thing you ever return is `i` which is `numeric`;
2. You only explicitly return something when all conditions are met, which means if the conditions are not all good, you do not return anything ... this is the same as `return(NULL)` which is also not `character` (try `vapply(1:2, function(a) return(NULL), character(1))`);
3. You explicitly set `fract[1] = NaN` and then test `!is.nan(fract)`, so you will never get anything; and
4. (Likely a typo) You reference `y[I]` (capital "i") which is an error unless `I` is defined somewhere (which is no longer a syntax error but is now a logical error).

If I fix the code (remove `NaN` assignment) in your `for` loop, I get

```
indexPoints
#  [1]  3  4  5  6 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 18 20 21 25 26 28 29 30 31 32 34 35 38 39
# [26] 40 42 43 44 45 47 48 49 50 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 64 66 68 70 71 72
# [51] 74 75 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 86 88 89 90 91 92 93 95 96 97 98 99
```

If we really want to do this one at a time (I recommend against it, read below), then there are a few methods:

1. Use `Filter` to only return the indices where the condition is true:

   ```
   indexPoints2 <- Filter(function(i) {
     fract <- x[i] / y[i]
     !is.nan(fract) && (fract > (threshFC+1) | fract < (1/(threshFC+1)))
   }, seq_along(seqVec))
   identical(indexPoints, indexPoints2)
   # [1] TRUE
   ```
2. Use `vapply` *correctly*, returning an integer either way:

   ```
   indexPoints3 <- vapply(seq_along(seqVec), function(i) {
     fract <- x[i] / y[i]
     if (!is.nan(fract) && (fract > (threshFC+1) | fract < (1/(threshFC+1)))) i else NA_integer_
   }, integer(1))
   str(indexPoints3)
   #  int [1:100] NA NA 3 4 5 6 NA NA NA 10 ...
   indexPoints3 <- indexPoints3[!is.na(indexPoints3)]
   identical(indexPoints, indexPoints3)
   # [1] TRUE
   ```

   (Notice the explicit return of a specific type of NA, that is `NA_integer_`, so that `vapply` is happy.)
3. We can instead just return the `logical` if the index matches the conditions:

   ```
   logicalPoints4 <- vapply(seq_along(seqVec), function(i) {
     fract <- x[i] / y[i]
     !is.nan(fract) && (fract > (threshFC+1) | fract < (1/(threshFC+1)))
   }, logical(1))
   head(logicalPoints4)
   # [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
   identical(indexPoints, which(logicalPoints4))
   # [1] TRUE
   ```

But really, there is absolutely no need to use `vapply` or any of the `apply` functions, since this can be easily (and much more efficiently) checked as a vector:

```
fract <- x/y # all at once
indexPoints5 <- which(!is.nan(fract) & (fract > (threshFC+1) | fract < (1/(threshFC+1))))
identical(indexPoints, indexPoints5)
# [1] TRUE
```

(If you don't use `which`, you'll see that it gives you a `logical` vector indicating if the conditions are met, similar to bullet 3 above with `logicalPoints4`.)